# Is there some similar spine decomposition for Galton-Watson tree in supercritical case whose offsprings have positive probability to have no child?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, trees

I am interested in the supercritical GW tree whose offsprings have positive probability to have no child conditioned on the event that the tree is not dead.

Comment: The keyword is "backbone decomposition".

Answer (score 1):

Lyons, Russell, Robin Pemantle, and Yuval Peres. "Conceptual proofs of L log L criteria for mean behavior of branching processes." The Annals of Probability (1995): 1125-1138.  https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2244865.pdf?casa_token=VHoIvAHythwAAAAA:HGRlhOHlpz7_CFg71uL4Uj6Qc6t81IOgK3rl7T1HvOcRlYGVZPQ1HezY8-0DyLiwGRrfBf0j7GzOJFWqg7PvD2UoHT2oeAKbOkbHjutSRlpYTbL1SXY